# How to get table data by using cypress?

Tags: cypress

I want to get a data in table which is made by two tables, that means header is in tableA and body is in tableB. And want to store the data into an object which key is the header from table, value is the data from table, then push into an array so that I can use it later.

I'm trying with below cypress scripts to get whole test data including headers and values, but I find it's impossible due to **asynchronization**.

```js
    GetHeadersAndValuesOfAPage(){
        cy.xpath(boNaviNodePage.tableObjs.tableHeader).then((allHeaders) => {
            let headerName, dataArr=[];
            for (let i = 1; i <= allHeaders.length; i++) {
                cy.xpath('(' + boNaviNodePage.tableObjs.tableHeader + ')[' + i + ']').then((headerElement) => {
                    headerName = headerElement.text().trim();
                    cy.xpath(boSharedPage.boSharedPageObjs.dataLineNumer).its('length').then(length =>{
                        let Obj={}
                        for (let j = 1; j <= length; j++) {
                            cy.xpath(boNaviNodePage.tableObjs.tableValue.replace('lineNumber', `${j}`) + '[' + i + ']').then((valueElement) => {
                                if (headerName.length !== 0) {
                                    Obj[headerName] = valueElement.text().trim();
                                }
                            })
                        }
                        if(Object.keys(Obj).length === 0 && Obj.constructor === Object){
                            dataArr.push(Obj);
                        }
                    })
                    cy.log(`Now, we've alreay have ${dataArr.length} data `); // dataArr.length = 1,2,3... until the last one
                })
                cy.log(`Not in loop, data length: ${dataArr.length}`);// **dataArr.length = 0**
            }
            cy.log(`Finally we've already have ${dataArr.length} data!`);// **dataArr.length = 0**
        });
    }
```

Could anybody who familiar with cypress help to check how can I make it work?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fixed by using alias.